# Problema migrando proyecto de Xcode 8.3.3 a Xcode 9.3

Tags: xcode, swift3, objective-c

Mi proyecto no tiene ningún problema de compilación, pero, a la hora de visualizar mi storyboard en los emuladores, se ve con la mitad de la pantalla en blanco.

[image: el emulador tiene una parte en blanco, aún así, es funcional al 100%]

Por el contrario, cuando ejecuto en un dispositivo real, me funciona. No he cambiado nada de mi storyboard ni mis .xib (comprobado que en dispositivos reales funciona). He de añadir que, este es un proyecto que retomé de un compañero, y su explicación fue que en Xcode 9 no se han puesto los autolayouts y constraints.

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe? ¿Es un problema de los nuevos emuladores de Xcode 9? ¿Porqué en Xcode 8.3.3 funciona y en Xcode 9 no?

Comment: Lo que necesitas creo que es entender que son las Constraints.
Te paso un enlace que te lo explica a ver si te sirve de ayuda.
https://www.efectoapple.com/introduccion-a-auto-layout-parte-i/